# HTML/JS: appendTo doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to dynamically append a Table/List to HTML page. My code as follows:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
            <title>Lead Manager</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
            <script src="themes/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="themes/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
            </head>
        <body id="body" name="body">
           <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
                <h1>Lead Manager</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                <h2>List of Leads</h2>          
            </div>
           </div>

        </body>             

     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) { 
            //var data = Android.getLeads();
            var data = [{"status":"1","name":"1","campaign":"1","date":"1"},{"status":"2","name":"2","campaign":"2","date":"2"}];
            var items = [];
            var date;
            var name;
            var status;
            //eval(" var x = " + data + " ; ");         
            //var y = JSON.stringify(x);                        
            $.each(data, function(key,val){
                items.push('<tr><td>' + val.date + '</tr></td>');   
            });                         
            var text = $('<table/>', { html: items.join('')});
            $('<table/>', {     
                html: items.join('')
                }).appendTo('body');                        
          });         
       </script>
</html>
```

The Items[] variable is getting filled with the tr and td values. However, the appendTo, doesnt work. The JSON as you can see doesnt require eval as its already in the format required.

Please can you help?

Comment: loos fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n7eN2/1/

Comment: oops! then, any good reason for not getting this result in chrome?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: @ArunPJohny - confirmed - http://jsfiddle.net/Rbx7p/1/

Comment: There were no errors also.. Looks very strange..

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Can it be because of the css? I was using bootstrap mobile

Comment: even then the html markup should be created only the styling might change

Comment: Got it.. the issue was because of this:
<script src="themes/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Try $(document.body).append(your html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was mainly because of the jquery.mobile script as it wasnt allowing dynamic addition of html code.